# Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx) with valid c# constructor

Tags: c#, guid

```
var username = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
var userid = new Guid(username);
```

Why is this causing a Guid FormatException to occur?

> Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).

The constructor for Guid allows me to pass in a string and I passed in a string so it should work!

Comment: What is the value of `username`?

Comment: The guid string that you can pass to the constructor should follow that format. You can't set any string in there. Did you want to use string.GetHashCode instead?

Comment: the username is an email address

Comment: What do you expect `userid` to look like?

Comment: I thought the email was used like a seed. I see my error now

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code - you probably seen it long time ago but it is still applicable - showing all necessary date inline like `var userid = new Guid("bob@example.com");` is important for questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the claim e-mail contains the e-mail and not the object guid. Check the debugger which claim contains the GUID. Generally the `NameIdentifies` is the claim you are searching for:

```
User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)
```

Answer (score 4):

The error message really says it all - `Guid`'s constructor doesn't take any odd string, it expects a string in a very specific format - "32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)", e.g. "12345678-1234-1234-1234-12345678".